# Interacting with Django Restful API using Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, django-rest-framework, angular-resource

I am trying to interact with my Django Restful API using $resource, but when I try a get or query, it returns > 7000 elements. It's as if it is returning each letter/component of the api individually. I also tried using '/api/projects.json/' (following the Angularjs Tutorial) and '/api/projects/?format=json' to query the api, but I get the same result. What am I missing?

My Service:

```
(function(){
angular
    .module('userdash.projects.services')
    .factory('ProjectServ', ProjectServ);

ProjectServ.$inject = ['$resource'];

function ProjectServ($resource){
    return $resource('api/projects/', {},{
        create: {method: 'POST'},
        get: {method: 'GET', isArray:false},
        remove: {method: 'DELETE'},
        update: {method: 'PUT'}
    })
}
})();
```

---

My Controller:

```
(function(){

angular
    .module('userdash.projects.controllers')
    .controller('ProjectController', ProjectController);

ProjectController.$inject = ['$scope','ProjectServ'];

function ProjectController($scope, ProjectServ){
     ProjectServ.get().$promise.then(function(data){
        $scope.projects = ProjectServ.get();
     });
}
```

---

My Directive HTML:

```
<div class="col-sm-9 col-sm-offset-3 col-md-10 col-md-offset-2 main" ng-controller="ProjectController">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4" ng-repeat="project in projects">
      <h2>Heading</h2>
      <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui. </p>
      <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="#" role="button">View details &raquo;</a></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image: Using bootstraps Dashboard template, I get ~>7000 elements in the promise]

[image: My RESTfull API]

Comment: you should set project value in callback function of query like `ProjectServ.query().$promise.then(function(data) { $scope.projects = ProjectServ.query();})`

Comment: @pankajParkar, I tried that but it returned the same response

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you don't need to specify every method if you are using the default ones. Use `$resource('api/projects/')` instead of:

```
function ProjectServ($resource){
    return $resource('api/projects/', {},{
        create: {method: 'POST'},
        get: {method: 'GET', isArray:false},
        remove: {method: 'DELETE'},
        update: {method: 'PUT'}
    })
}
```

In the second place, and to resolve your problem, you should assign the data variable that comes in the promise to your local array like this:

```
function ProjectController($scope, ProjectServ){
     ProjectServ.get().$promise.then(function(data){
        $scope.projects = data;
     });
}
```

Cheers!

Comment: Thank you for the help Cristiam, but the problem was my definition of my get method. IsArray should be True, plus a stripTrailingSlashes: true.

Comment: What about calling the get in the callback? was that correct?